# How to get current user email address FirebaseAuth/Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I want to get the email of the currently signed in user, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.
I presume it should be something similar to:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().getEmail(); //The .getEmail() part is made up
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using the [Firebase Auth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth) package:

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; 

Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async { 
GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn(); 
GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication; 
FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithGoogle( 
accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
 idToken: googleAuth.idToken, ); 

// get email here
print("signed in " + user.email); 
return user; }
```

And handling the login:

```
_handleSignIn() .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user)) .catchError((e) => print(e));
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to do... you just have to get the current user with `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` and get the email by adding `.email`

You will get the email of the current user

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the signed-in user information, you should first call the `currentUser()` method, and then call for the `email` and save it into a string variable, like this:

```dart
    final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    String userEmail;
    void getCurrentUserEmail() async {
    final user =
              await _auth.currentUser().then((value) => userEmail = value.email);
    }
```

Another way of doing this is by saving `currentUser()` into a variable then fetching for related information such as `email` or `phoneNumber`  by typing `.` and choosing any value you want , 
like this:

```
    final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    dynamic user;
    String userEmail;
    String userPhoneNumber;

    void getCurrentUserInfo() async {
      user = await _auth.currentUser();
      userEmail = user.email;
      userPhoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
      }
```