# How to get current logged in user's email with Flutter Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Currently, I am trying to build a simple android app, along the process its quite successful with the firebase authentication. But now I faced one problem where I wanted to show the logged in user's email in my drawer widget that I used to sign in with firebase authentication but I just cant find the solution up to date. I cant show any working code because I cant find any usable examples online. Can anyone of you help me please ?

Comment: Did you look over the API documentation for the User object? https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html

Comment: Alternative to Doug's link, is the FlutterFire guide which has an example here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state

Comment: Alternative to Doug and Franks link is a [myriad of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D%5Bflutter%5Dget+email+address) here on SO about working with users emails and in particular [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191832/how-to-get-current-user-email-address-firebaseauth-flutter) may be of interest. It's a good idea to do a little research before asking questions as someone else may have already asked it (and have a great answer)!